# How to convert a long character string to a dataframe when natural separators are lacking? (R)

Tags: r, string, split

I'm looking for a solution that takes the string above and create a data frame of 8 columns. This might be a very complex task to solve. I will be very happy for any advice on how to come closer to a solution on this issue. I provide a code example below.

```
library(tibble)

string <- "Organisationsnummer Företag (huvudorg) Anordnare (enhet) Utbildning Sunkod Kommunkod Medverkande org Ansökningsomgång\n0212000212 Arboga Kommun Arboga kommun, Vuxenutbildningen Specialistundersköterska inom demens 415723rb 1984 Arboga Kommun, Socialförvaltningen Yrkeshögskoleutbildning 2018\n0212000156 Borås Kommun Borås Stad – Borås Yrkeshögskola Autoingenjör 525523af 1490 Rebel Walls Yrkeshögskoleutbildning 2019"

DF <- tibble(Organisationsnummer = c("0212000212", "0212000156"),
       'Företag (huvudorg)' = c("Arboga Kommun", "Borås Kommun"),
       'Anordnare (enhet)' = c("Arboga kommun, Vuxenutbildningen", "Borås Stad – Borås Yrkeshögskola"),
       Utbildning = c("Specialistundersköterska inom demens", "Autoingenjör"),
       Sunkod = c("415723rb", "525523af"),
       Kommunkod = c("1984", "1490"),
       'Medverkande org' = c("Arboga Kommun, Socialförvaltningen", "Rebel Walls"),
       Ansökningsomgång = c("Yrkeshögskoleutbildning 2018", "Yrkeshögskoleutbildning 2019"))
```

I'm struggling with how to chop up the string in the correct columns because natural separators doesn’t exists (This is data from a large pdf-file I have scanned into R using tesseract OCR).

I want the columns to be created from characters in the first row. I can’t use a single separator like white space due to spaces used in three columns ‘Företag (huvudorg)’, ‘Anordnare (enhet)’ and ‘Medverkande org’.

And now comes the main problem. Some columns are predictable in that sense that they are separated by space. ‘Organisationsnummer’ is always a 10-digit number. ‘Sunkod’ is always six numbers and two letters. ‘Kommunkod’ is always a four-digit number. ‘Ansökningsomgång’ is either ”Yrkeshögskoleutbildning 2018” or ”Yrkeshögskoleutbildning 2019”.

The second, third, fourth and seventh column can look very different from case to case. They can have one, two, three or more spaces, a comma or “-“.

How can I begin to address this problem? Very grateful for any help.

Comment: Do you have patterns you could use? Like e.g. parentheses or domain? You could then build rules like "if word is recognized as  for example a domain, it belongs to the word before"

Comment: begin with `strsplit(string, "\\n")`.

Comment: Could one way be to loop throu all lines after the strsplit and add seven separators for each line in some systematic way?